# query data in Excel from power bi web app

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

When we upload an Excel workbook to SharePoint , every table in that workbook is exposed as an OData feed that can be used in Power Query.

Similarly is there any way we also query data in Excel from power bi web app [https://app.powerbi.com] ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do it directly from Service.

Open any Worksapce you could contribute to -> New -> Dataset -> Excel/CSV. That's it. There are some other ways of doing this. But that one is a great starting point for a newbie.